# How to pass variable to method properly? (python)

Tags: python, syntax, ros

I am trying to clean up my code but I am new to python so I'm pretty sure my syntax is wrong. I wrote a simple controller to have a variable `message_lx_setPoint` approach the value of a set point `message_lx_setPoint`. I am using *robot operating system* so the script is being looped by that. As it is, it works fine, the value of `message_lx_current` approaches the value of the setPoint. Below is the code I made for that:

```
#defs
increment = 0.1

#setPoint values
message_lx_setPoint = 5.0 #value set by some controller(?)
message_ly_setPoint = 5.0

#current values
message_lx_current = 0.0 #value set by some sensor(?)
message_ly_current = 0.0

def approach_lx_setPoint():
    global message_lx_current, message_lx_setPoint, increment

    if message_lx_current < message_lx_setPoint:
        print("current is less than set point")
        message_lx_current += increment

    elif message_lx_current == message_lx_setPoint:
        print("current is equal to set point")
        message_lx_current = 0.0

    elif message_lx_current > message_lx_setPoint:
        print("current is greater than set point")
        message_lx_current -= increment

    return message_lx_current

def approach_ly_setPoint():
    global message_ly_current, message_ly_setPoint, increment

    if message_ly_current < message_ly_setPoint:
        print("current is less than set point")
        message_ly_current += increment

    elif message_ly_current == message_ly_setPoint:
        print("current is equal to set point")
        message_ly_current = 0.0

    elif message_ly_current > message_ly_setPoint:
        print("current is greater than set point")
        message_ly_current -= increment

    return message_ly_current

def main():
    approach_lx_setPoint()
    approach_ly_setPoint()
    print(message_lx_current)
    print(message_ly_current)
```

I have to do this for *6* different variables, so my code start to get bloated; I have to make 6 methods in total to control all 6 variables. I want to make it so that I only make one *single* method, I pass the variable to be controlled and the variable to be the set point and it executes from there. I am thinking something like this:

```
#same variables as before

def approachSetPoint(current, target):
    global increment

    if current < target:
        print("current is less than set point")
        current += increment

    elif current == target:
        print("current is equal to set point")
        current = 0.0

    elif current > target:
        print("current is greater than set point")
        current -= increment

    return current

def main():
    approachSetPoint(message_lx_current, message_lx_setPoint)
    approachSetPoint(message_ly_current, message_ly_setPoint)
    print(message_lx_current)
    print(message_ly_current)
```

I am hoping that the result of this will be that rather than having one `approachSetPoint` *def* for each variable to be controlled, I will only have *one* approachSetPoint def, and all I have to do is call it in main with the proper variables and it'll do the thing.

I tried this and I got no errors or anything, however, the values were NOT being updated(?). I'm assuming I'm just not properly linking the variable I'm passing as an argument to the one that is modified in the method. Any idea how to approach a behavior like I describes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Group “variables” into “objects” and consider combining “multiplicity variables” into “collections”. Look to pull out common code, especially where re-assignment of a variable is not required. Python only supports call-by-object-sharing (no true call-by-reference); and these objects are the core method of state.

Comment: In the case above there are really several pairs of values (representable as paired object members, or even tuple components) associated with state. In the case of a tuple, destructuring may also be useful - depending on overall API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the results outside the function between runs:

```
message_lx_current = y_current = 0.0
message_lx_setpoint = message_ly_setpoint = 5.0

def approach_setpoint(current, setpoint, increment=0.1):
    if current < setpoint:
        print("current is less than set point")
        current += increment
    elif current == setpoint:
        print("current is equal to set point")
        current = 0.0
    elif current > setpoint:
        print("current is greater than set point")
        current -= increment
    return current

def main():
    message_lx_current = approach_setpoint(message_lx_current, message_lx_setpoint)
    message_ly_current = approach_setpoint(message_ly_current, message_ly_setpoint)
    print(message_lx_current)
    print(message_ly_current)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Just had to add ```global <vars>``` in ```main()```